# SQL Jobs/SSIS Packages rely on DB

Tags: sql-server

Would there be a way to find which SSIS packages are relying on a specific database instead of going through each SSIS package and retrieving the connection?

Thanks,
Pratap

Comment: Check this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shiyangqiu/2016/08/03/extract-all-the-connection-strings-from-ssis-packages/

Comment: Also, if your packages are in the MSDB database, you can query them via select top 1 cast(cast([packagedata] as varbinary(max)) as xml) from [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages] (nolock) and extract the datasource from the xml.

Comment: If not you can check the description on the job and if it isn't there you will have to check each one.

Comment: Thank you! I will try today and let you know!